# change from hyperlink to link btn

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, webforms, asplinkbutton

Had to change from asp:hyperlink to asp:linkButton, can no longer use navigateUrl in link button...any suggestions?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="InvoiceLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Invoices/List.aspx">
           <asp:Label id="labelBindfromHomeToInvoice" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('Site_Name') %>"/>
        </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: If you dont need this control server side you could use a normal <a href="/Invoices/List.aspx"><asp:Label ....     </a > . If you DO need it on the server side you could use PostbackURL instead (as long as your happy to "POST" the form data of this page to the other. Or use OnClientClick to perform a JS redirect OR use OnClick and hook up a serverside event handler and redirect from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkButton` doesn't work that way. `LinkButton` is more like a `Button` with a Hyperlink appeareance.
So you can handle the OnClick Event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="InvoiceLink" runat="server" OnClick="InvoiceLink_Click">
    <asp:Label id="labelBindfromHomeToInvoice" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('Site_Name') %>"/>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

In the CodeBehind

```
protected void InvoiceLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Invoices/List.aspx");
}
```

**EDITED**

I will improve this answer. The main difference between `HyperLink` and `LinkButton` is that `HyperLink` will not PostBack, it just simply request the NavigateURL to the server. The `LinkButton` is just a normal `Button`. This means that it will PostBack the server, with all the advantages and disadvantages to doing this (sending ViewState for example, update the controls, etc)

If you need just to redirect to another page, probably the best choice it will be `HyperLink`

Answer (score 1):

LinkButton uses `PostBackUrl`, because you "post" the data to another url.

Answer (score 1):

On a link button you use the `PostBackUrl`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="InvoiceLink" runat="server"
     PostBackUrl="~/Invoices/List.aspx">
```